# java.lang.LinkageError after Eclipse P2 Update

Tags: java, eclipse, equinox, p2

We're using Tycho to build our features/bundles and using `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director` to update the product.

I've noticed that the update causes a `java.lang.LinkageError` when the product is running during the update. I guess the problem is that some binary classes are already loaded when the update is excuting and they don't match with the new classes which getting loaded maybe after the update.

I couldn't find any information about a issue like this.

Note that the p2 director is invoked from an external process and not within eclipse itself what's causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc of the LinkageError (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/LinkageError.html) is pretty self-explaining:

> Subclasses of LinkageError indicate that a class has some dependency on another class; however, the latter class has incompatibly changed after the compilation of the former class.

What I can imagine in your case: some bundles without explicit Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment manifest constraint have been installed, and some users have JVM which are not compatible with it. Other bundles depend on those and when it comes to class loading, you get the LinkageError.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It's not the case that the Bundle-RequiredEE changes. All users use >= Java 7. And i'm always update all features so there shouldn't be anything that is incompatible.

Comment: It was just a guess. Detailed stack trace could help.